# Attach tmux to pty after reptyr?

Tags: tmux, pty, reptyr

I've got reptyr to "open a new pty" by doing:

```
reptyr -L 7969
```

where 7969 is the PID of rabbitmq-server.
The output of reptyr is

```
Opened a new pty: /dev/pts/25
```

but how do I attach tmux to that pty?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

I may misunderstand what you are trying to do but if your aim is to move the process with PID 7969 into tmux then you can achieve it by running `reptyr` inside `tmux`:

```
$ tmux send-key -t mysession:mywindow "reptyr 7969^M"
```

That runs `reptyr` **INSIDE** the tmux session in the shell window at `mysession:mywindow`. If you need to create the session first:

```
$ tmux new -d -s mysession -n mywindow
$ tmux send-key -t mysession:mywindow "reptyr 7969^M"
```

To get `^M`, press `CONTROL_V` and hit `ENTER`.